# Reading a text file

Tags: java, string, char

I need help on this code.
The input is stored in a text file like this:

```
First:3 6 
Secon:3 9
```

The output is:

```
First:3 6 

The Maximum number is6

The sum is9


Secon:3 9 


The Maximum number is9

The sum is12
```

But my desired output should be :

```
    The Maximum number is6
    The sum is12
```

So,it applies Math.max() on the first line only.
And,it add the second line numbers.

Please help.

```
import java.io.*;

public class cape 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{

  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PC4599/Desktop/cape.txt"); // Open the text file.
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);// Get the object of DataInputStream
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String MyString;


  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((MyString = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {

  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (MyString);


  Character c = new Character(MyString.charAt(6));
  Character c2 = new Character(MyString.charAt(8));



  String s = c.toString();
  String s2 = c2.toString(); 


  int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
  int i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

    int sum=i+i2;
  System.out.println("The Maximum number is"+ Math.max(i, i2));
  System.out.println("The sum is"+ sum);

  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
   //Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework, if so please retag.

Comment: What if you have `First:36 63` and `Secon:39 909`?

Comment: Is the file always going to have just 2 lines?

Comment: No ,it is not a homework.I am learning Java on my own,and am practicing different problems.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
    String[] nums1 = br.readLine().split(":")[1].split(" ");
    String[] nums2 = br.readLine().split(":")[1].split(" ");
    br.close();
    System.out.println("The maximum number is " + Math.max(Integer.parseInt(nums1[0]), Integer.parseInt(nums1[1])));
    System.out.println("The sum is " + (Integer.parseInt(nums2[0]) + Integer.parseInt(nums2[1])));    
}
```

If your file has more than just 2 lines, it shouldn't be hard to employ a similar method using a loop.

Comment: Thank you,it works well for me.I did not know of the split() method before,thanks.

Comment: What about if I have three numbers instead of 2 : e.g First: 4 8 2 ,please help!

Comment: Ok,I got it: System.out.println("The Minimum is "+ Math.min(Math.min(Integer.parseInt(nums2[0]),Integer.parseInt(nums2[1])),Integer.parseInt(nums2[2])));

Answer (score 1):

You can count the line numbers and print the right thing for each line:

```
int line = 0;
...
if (line == 0) System.out.println("The Maximum number is"+ Math.max(i, i2));
if (line == 1) System.out.println("The sum is"+ sum);
line++;
```